# How to change links of posts in admin panel of Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress like backend and react like front end and they are on the different subdomains. Therefore links in list of posts follow to the wrong place. So how to change links to connect posts on front- and backend sides?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Wordpress Dashboard. Options - > Permalinks. And there u can choose :)